# How do I make my MX880 Canon prints come out in the same colors as on the screen?

Tags: lightroom, printing, display-calibration

I have a Canon MX880 printer which I recently bought. For some reason, prints from Adobe Lightroom come out with bad colors (i.e. not the same as on screen, though not altogether different). I played around with a bunch of setting and couldn't find something to make it work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to calibrate your monitor.Search [display-calibration](http://photo.stackexchange.com/search?q=display-calibration)

Comment: Indeed I forgot to add that display calibration is the first thing I tried.

Comment: How did you calibrate your monitor? Trial and Error or did you use hardware like [Huey, Spyder, Etc.](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/search?Ntt=display+calibration&N=0&InitialSearch=yes) to calibrate it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I need to calibrate my monitor to match my printer?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/18167/do-i-need-to-calibrate-my-monitor-to-match-my-printer)

Comment: Alen, I used only software tools....

Comment: @Shwouchk get Pantone Huey it's about 75$ and it does decent job.

Comment: All my wireless prints came out 2 to 3 f-stops darker than the original elcetroinic image. The immediate solution was to print directly from the SD card in the slot on the front of the printer and that worked well. Seems that the wireless transmission lost the colors.

Comment: I think it's meant to be an answer to the question, actually. What's going on here, I think, is that Canon printers have an "auto-enhance" feature that they apply to photos printed from the SD slot directly. (Just as, for example, Shutterfly automatically amps up the saturation and contrast unless you tell them not to.) When you print from a computer over the network, that's not necessarily applied. So it's not that the colors are lost in transmission, but rather that the direct-printed photos get extra spices applied. That doesn't solve the Lightroom color calibration problem, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For best results you need a "color profile" to match your monitor to the color palette / gamut / system / ... that you are using AND you want a color profile to do the same thing for your printer. Then you see on screen what the image should look like and your printer interprets this correctly. Both are necessary for serious work. If you set printer to screen and the screen is not correctly "profiles" YOU will see good results on screen and printer BUT your electronic images will probably not appear correct to anyone else.

There is more on web about this than you'd want to wade through, but it doesn't take much effort to get a good enough idea for practical purposes.

Some printer manufacturers provide formal profiles for their printers.

Here is an excellent introduction re ICC and ICM profiles and printers -
 [Understanding Printer Colour Management](http://www.luminous-landscape.com/tutorials/understanding-series/und-print-mgmt.shtml)

Good [Introduction to Icc Profiles and Their Use](http://www.drycreekphoto.com/Learn/profiles.htm) - monitors and printers.

An about.com tutorial - main value is in a number of useful links provided - [Calibrate Your Printer](http://desktoppub.about.com/cs/colorcalibration/a/cal_printer.htm)

If you have money - [Chromix](http://desktoppub.about.com/gi/o.htm?zi=1/XJ&zTi=1&sdn=desktoppub&cdn=compute&tm=38&f=10&su=p284.13.342.ip_p504.6.342.ip_&tt=2&bt=0&bts=0&zu=http%3A//www.chromix.com/)

[Adding a co or profile to Windows XP](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/icm_add_color_profile_printer.mspx?mfr=true)

[Wikipedia - color management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_management)

Comment: There is one thing in particular that baffles me:

Assuming I profiled the monitor correctly, what do the different settings in lightroom and in the printer driver dialog mean?

Comment: Specifically, I can choose a color profile in Lightroom, or leave it as "printer managed". In the printer dialog I can also choose "Color/Intensity" to auto or manual, where if I choose manual, I get a window with a tab called "Color Adjustment" which is pretty self explanatory, and "Matching".
Under "Matching" There is an option to select either "Driver Matching", "ICC Profile Matching" (ICM) or None. In ICM There is also an option to choose "standard" or "Adobe RGB" input profile, and then "saturation", "perceptual", etc.. What does each option mean and when is it appropriate?